# Restrict RowEditor when CheckBox Column is clicked

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I have a grid with a CheckBoxColumn and RowEditor plugin that is configured with clicksToEdit: 1

**How can I prevent the RowEditor to open when the CheckBoxColumn is clicked?** Cause I am not able to select more than one row at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RowEditor have the 'beforeedit' event. The second parameter of this event is a edit event object - e.

Edit event object have a property 'cancel' - set it to true to cancel the edit or return false from your handler.

So, we can just set it in 'true' or 'false' to disable or enable the RowEditor:

```
    {
        xtype: 'checkbox',
        fieldLabel: 'Disable row Editor',
        listeners: {
            change: function(cb) {
                var editor = cb.up('grid').editingPlugin;
                editor.on({
                    beforeedit: function(plugin, e) {
                        e.cancel = cb.checked;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Please, see live example on jsfiddle: [**http://jsfiddle.net/p7Vzu/**](http://jsfiddle.net/p7Vzu/)

Comment: I don't want to disable the roweditor. It should just don't trigger if the checkbox-column get clicked

Comment: @seba I understand. What's the difference? Just cancel editing when checkbox column get clicked. Show your code please, and I'll show you an example.

Comment: Simply use a grid with this `columns: [{ header:'Required',dataIndex:'Required', editor: {  xtype: 'checkbox', value: false, inputValue: 'true', uncheckedValue: 'false' } },],
selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel')`

Comment: One additional question: is there any way to select additonal rows for the whole checkbox cell? currently it unselect all if I don't hit exactly the checkbox itself.

Comment: @seba Set 'checkOnly' property of selModel to 'true' and edit listener: http://jsfiddle.net/B3fW3/1/